# How to de-select a JList item from my program

Tags: java, jlist

I have a JList, and a JButton, user can click an item in the JList or they can click the button, when the button is clicked how do I de-select (change the selected list item bgcolor to normal, in other words, nothing in the JList will be selected after the button is clicked) the item from the JList ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [JList](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) should have a [`clearSelection()` method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#clearSelection%28%29) that you can call.

Comment: I was having a problem finding a way to do this - but this easily cleared it up. Thanks much, though its a shame there is not a simpler way to clear the selection (such as say, setting the selected index to -1 or something).